# generate regular expressions from a list of strings

Tags: c++, data-structures

Original problem:

I am reading something from regex format, expands it and writing it out. This list can become huge while writing it out.

While writing it out, I do not have the original regex data. So, I will have to create regexes out of the strings which I have.

A couple of cases while reading and writing:

Say, read regular expression is:

```
abc/*
```

Since 'abc' can have only 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D'(Have this list with me), Above would be translated to list of strings as

```
"abc/A", "abc/B", "abc/C", "abc/D" -- 1
```

Say, another read regular expression is:

```
def/*/A
```

Since 'def' can have only 'x', 'y', 'x'(Have this list with me), Above would be translated to list of strings as

```
"def/x/A", "def/x/A", "def/x/A" -- 2
```

I have already said that I do not have original regular expressions now. All I have is list of strings. I will have to create regexes out of statements number 1 and 2.

From number 1, I should get

```
 abc/*
```

From number 2, I should get

```
 def/*/A
```

which are the original.

Question: Which data structure would be efficient to solve this problem. I have thought of using tries & Aho–Corasick algorithm but could not get a clear solution at top of my head till now.

I would be happy to expand the question more in case it is not clear. Please consider that * will not match /, //, or anything except characters.

Comment: I don't see any difference between the first two examples. Why would it be possible to generate a regex for the first, but not the second?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, "abc/D" is missing in second example. If I make regex as 'abc/*' then 'abc/D' would also be considered while reading abc/*

Comment: Also, technically the regex `abc/*` would match `abc`, `abc/`, `abc//` and so on with the slashes. Perhaps you mean `abc/.`? Or considering your comment (which should be elaborated on in the question itself) `abc/[ABCD]`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, Yes, you are right. My bad. We can make regex in second example as well. Let me edit.

Comment: And regarding the difference between the two first examples, how would you be able to tell the difference between them? How do you get the strings in the list? What is your input? What is the purpose of the program you're making? What is the *actual* problem you're having, and you want to use regular expressions to solve? And remember the old saying "I have a problem. I solved it with regular expressions. Now I have *two* problems." Regular expressions are maybe not the solution to your actual problem?

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by *"if I tell "abc"..."*

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, The problem is : I am reading something from regex format, expands it and writing it out. Now, while writing it out, I do not have the original regex data. So, I will have to create regexes out of it.

Comment: @PasserBy, Just like there are 26 characters in English, You can assume that 'abc' would have only 4 options. :)

Comment: So you want to *reverse engineer* a regular expression from some text? That's really impossible. It might be possible to *guess* one of the many possible alternatives, but it might not be the regex actually used. Perhaps you should consider a design where you also save the regex so you can get it later (for whatever unknown reason you want it)?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, Should not be impossible. I am sure that it is hard problem to solve though. Might need lot of intelligence to solve.

Comment: Again with the second example, if that's all you have as input to your program, how do you know that the `D` is an alternative? Do you get the list (`A`, `B`, `C` and `D`) as well from somewhere? How do you know that `abc/D` wasn't just in the input to begin with? All three alternatives you show are still valid for `abc/[ABCD]`. There are just to many details missing to be able to help you. Not to mention that you haven't told us what you have tried and how your attempt didn't work. Please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, I see. Let me make it more clear.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, All cool now?

Comment: I don't think you are creating regular expressions. I think you are un-expanding wildcards. Surely you just have to verify that the position of "A" in "abc/A" is the same as "B" in "abc/B" etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a hard problem to solve.

Good possible solution:

Step 1: Convert list of strings into a finite automation. As I mentioned, I shall use 'Aho–Corasick algorithm' to do that.

Step 2: Transform the finite automation into a regular expression... Something like this: https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/2016/how-to-convert-finite-automata-to-regular-expressions